# How to Compare Two dataTable and Update non matched rows in a DataTable which gives the resultDataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

### MasterData

Id     Name

1        CENTRAL

2    EAST

3    EAST CENTRAL

4    EAST COASTAL

5    NORTH

6    NORTH WEST

7    SOUTH

8    SOUTH CENTRAL

9    WEST

### Data Received

Id          Name         Value

1          CENTRAL      125.65

5          NORTH        553.21

### i want the Result to be as followes

Id           Name                    Value

1        CENTRAL                   125.65

2        EAST                         0.0

3        EAST CENTRAL               0.0

4        EAST COASTAL           0.0

5        NORTH                  553.21

6        NORTH WEST             0.0 

7        SOUTH                  0.0

8        SOUTH CENTRAL          0.0

9        WEST                  0.0

Please note all are Datatable how can i Get the Result

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times.. please!

Comment: Great formatting skills.

Comment: It's hard to read. Is `Id` the PK in both table?

Comment: @SonerGönül I must know, how do you create links in comments? :)

Comment: @bas It is automatically.. You can see all links in http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#comment-formatting

Comment: @SonerGönül Awesome!  (I tried the same as in questions/answers, that seemed tricky enough :)). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say your `DataTable` are declared as following:

```
var dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

var dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(double)));
```

You can join it and get what you want with LINQ to objects:

```
var query = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
            join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on r1.Field<int>("Id") equals r2.Field<int>("Id") into r3
            from r4 in r3.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Id = r1.Field<int>("Id"),
                Name = r1.Field<string>("Name"),
                Value = r4 == null ? 0.00 : r4.Field<double>("Value")
            };
```

With that `IEnumerable<Anonymous_Type>` you can get `DataTable` object back, using `ToDataTable<T>` extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableToDataTableConverter
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                newRow[Props[i].Name] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

You can get `DataTable` from `query` with following statement:

```
var result = query.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine, but one more thing, Cai i get the ColumnName of 'Value' dyanamically, i will pass what should be the columnName as a Parameter in Select new i want that column name

Comment: You can set Column to another value at the end. Can't do that in select, because all anonymous type properties names have to be known compile time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, after getting the Result I changed DataColumn Name.to What ever i want. Sorry for my bad formating skills.